# react-native init AwesomeProject hang

Tags: react-native

I'm new with react, I"m trying to init with`react-native init AwesomeProject` but after a few minutes looks like the react is hang

```
npm verb addTmpTarball already have metadata; skipping unpack for babylon@5.8.35
npm verb correctMkdir /Users/dramirez/.npm correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb afterAdd /Users/dramirez/.npm/babylon/5.8.35/package/package.json not in flight; writing
npm verb correctMkdir /Users/dramirez/.npm correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb afterAdd /Users/dramirez/.npm/babylon/5.8.35/package/package.json written
npm http fetch 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bluebird/-/bluebird-2.10.2.tgz
npm verb addTmpTarball /var/folders/kr/js5391j510v9962s56x6c9rw0000gn/T/npm-22068-e178ea9f/registry.npmjs.org/bluebird/-/bluebird-2.10.2.tgz not in flight; adding
npm verb addTmpTarball already have metadata; skipping unpack for bluebird@2.10.2
npm verb correctMkdir /Users/dramirez/.npm correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb afterAdd /Users/dramirez/.npm/bluebird/2.10.2/package/package.json not in flight; writing
npm verb correctMkdir /Users/dramirez/.npm correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb afterAdd /Users/dramirez/.npm/bluebird/2.10.2/package/package.json written
loadDep:try-resolve → net ▌ ╢███████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
```

I'm not in china and I'm not sure what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours I decided to restart the computer and start the process again, and now it is working ;-( this is annoying

Comment: Occasionally you can get npm issues like this. Reseting cache sometimes helps!

Comment: Restarting also did not help me :-(

Answer (score 0):

Does it always hang on the same package? There is an option you can pass to react-native start, I think its reset-cache, maybe that will help

Comment: Yes it is in the same package "/bluebird/2.10.2/package/package.json"

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
react-native init ProjectName --verbose
```

it worked for me .

Answer (score -1):

VPN will solve that problem; according to my experiences. Maybe that's because of internet connection issue..